# Google+ Hangouts API: access participant video data and manipulate in canvas

Tags: google-plus, webrtc, google-hangouts

I am hoping to create the following Google+ Hangouts app using the API. The following steps describe it:

1. A button is provided to take a snapshot image of the participant video feed for background subtraction.
2. The participant enters the video feed. The feed is processed to subtract the background using the background image obtained in #1. The feed is processed (for example, so that the background is white and the foreground is black) to obtain something that can be treated as an image stream.
3. The processed feeds, represented as image streams, from all users are combined together programmatically and displayed on the canvas (for example, if white is TRUE and black is FALSE, I could do the pixel-wise logical AND of all participant feeds).

Can this be done with the current Google+ Hangouts API? If not, can you recommend a technology suite to do this (I would prefer WebRTC and not having to pay to relay video data through a server, i.e. P2P or a free infrastructure).

Notes:

I'm asking without having done much research.

I am aware that video feeds are not quite image streams, and that there will be lag and a degree of asynchrony.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Hangout API does not support the ability to capture audio or video. To learn more about the AV api we do support, check out https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.av/.